# Applying for H1B.. Can also apply for Schengen Business Visa for Germany when H1B is on processing?

Tags: usa, schengen, h1b-visas

I have been nominated for H1B CAP Lottery this year. This is on initial stages and within 3-4 days the same will be sent to USCIS for processing for the Lottery. Also, I need to travel to Germany for a week (on April 15-23) for conducting some business meetings with my current client. I already have invite letter for both (H1B and Schengen for Germany) from my two different client. There are some official procedures pending from my employer regarding Germany Trip and I will then start applying for my Schengen VISA on 2nd or 3rd week of this Month. So, by that time my H1B Application will be there to USCIS to process for the Lottery.
Note: As my Germany Trip is on 15th April, I will be getting my passport stamped with Schengen by 1st week of April or in worst case 2nd week of April. And the passport will be with me only till 23rd of April. So, for this total duration i.e. from 2nd week of March to 23rd of April, I can't give my Passport physically to any other authority for H1B Purpose.

My Questions are..
Q1. Is it possible to apply for a Schengen VISA for Germany for a week when I am already applied/sent my H1B CAP Application to USCIS?

Q2. If it's possible then is there any chance of cancellation of Schengen or H1B as two application is on process?

Q3. Should I need to take special approval if it's not possible in case?

Q4. Physical Original Passport is necessary for H1B Lottery? I mean do I need to sent this to USCIS or some other Authority for H1B Lottery for Processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you currently are in a third-party country.

Schengen is independent of US. So

- Q1. Yes
- Q2. No
- Q3. no
- Q4. No (see below)

You have much more relaxed timeline here. Even if you are selected in the H1B lottery, actual processing to having your visa papers approved takes a lot of time (about 3 weeks if your future employer go premium, 3-4 months if not). Then the originals of the visa papers (I-129 and I-797B - approval) are mailed to you, only then can you go the consulate with your passport and apply for a visa. And being subject to a cap, you have until October, 1st to get it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Your feedback helps me to have more relaxed breath as Germany trip is very important for me and I that cannot skip as well as H1B is for my future career. Both are equally important for me.
My Employer applied for Non-Premium H1B Cap for California. So according to your answer I will be having at least 3 months to submit my Original Passport to apply. Thanks!

Comment: @KingshukBanu, do not tarry, though. All kind of security screenings may delay issuance of your H-1 visa by quite some time these days (multiple month from submission of your application to the consulate application to getting visa stamp in passport in the worst case). So, I would suggest to switch to premium processing as soon as your employer learns your petition is selected and applying several month in advance.